# Area of polar curve

Tags: polar-coordinates, curves

So I have the polar curve

$r=\sqrt{|\sin(n\theta)|}$

Which I am trying to evaluate between $0$ and $2\pi$. By smashing it into wolfram it returns a constant value 4 for any $n$.

I tried calculating it manually (I suspect my calculation might be wrong), but I arrived at

$$\textrm{I}=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{2\pi}|\sin(n\theta)|= \left[\text{sgn}(\sin(nx))\frac{\cos(nx)}{n}\right]_{0}^{2\pi} $$ Which when looking at it can't be evaluated at $0$ or $2\pi$ with taking the limits. I suspect that whenever $n$ increases, the curve becomes "tighter", which could explain why in the integral stays permanently at 4, but I can't come up with a sound argument for it, so if someone could give me a pointer, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you please share the Wolfram URL as I find https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_0%5E%7B2%5Cpi%7D%5Csqrt%7B%7C%5Csin%28n%5Ccdot+t%29%7C%7Ddt

Comment: I'm evaluating the square of that function. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_0%5E%7B2%5Cpi%7D%7C%5Csin%284%5Ccdot+t%29%7Cdt  If you put in any value for $n$ it just returns 4.

Comment: The (single) integral solution to your problem should in the form

$$A=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{r^2}{2}~d\theta$$ as it is. But the correct answer is $A=2$ for all $n$. Apparently you dropped the factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ along the way.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I noticed that in hindsight, it should be $2$. I still can't justify it being $2$ though, as the limits of integration don't exist.

Answer (score 1):

The constant value of $4$ is normal
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}|\sin(t)|\,dt=\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin(t)\,dt-\int_{\pi}^{2\pi}\sin(t)\,dt=2+2$$
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}|\sin(2t)|\,dt=\int_{0}^{\frac\pi 2}\sin(2t)\,dt-\int_{\frac\pi 2}^{\pi}\sin(2t)\,dt+\int_{\pi}^{\frac{3\pi} 2}\sin(2t)\,dt-\int_{\frac{3\pi} 2}^{2\pi}\sin(2t)\,dt=1+1+1+1$$ Just continue.

Answer (score 0):

Use the variable change $t=n\theta$ to rewrite the integral as

$$\textrm{I}=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{2\pi}|\sin(n\theta)|d\theta
= \frac1{2n} \int_{0}^{2\pi n}|\sin t|dt$$

Due to the periodicity of the sine function

$$\textrm{I}
= \frac1{2n} \cdot n\int_{0}^{2\pi}|\sin t|dt
=\frac1{2}\int_{0}^{2\pi}|\sin t|dt =\frac1{2}\cdot 4 \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin tdt  = 2$$